# Dicas de APIs para a verificaçao de cotações em Bitcoin

Tags: python, bitcoin

Olá, sou novo nesse lance de Bitcoin, e procurei algumas APIs para verificar as cotações da moeda, no entanto as que achei eu não entendi muito bem como estas funcionam, alguém que entende mais do assunto pode me ajudar recomendando alguma API fácil de utilizar?

Comment: Fala @MatheusGrossi! A pergunta está bem ampla. Pode mostrar o que tentou? Ou estreitar a pergunta em uma API específica?

Comment: Então, eu  ando tentando fazer um script em Python que verifica a cotação da Bitcoin em tempo real, para que posteriormente eu use essa informação para outros fins, no entanto de inicio o intuito é apenas verificar o quanto esta vale no momento em que o script for executado...

Comment: Que API tem usado? Pode mostrar a parte que está fazendo a consulta nesse script?

Comment: Inicialmente eu usei uma que se chama Bitcoin-Python, e em relação ao script eu fiz vários "rascunhos" deste, no entanto nenhum deles me apresentou o resultado desejado, portanto estes foram excluídos, sem a possibilidade de recuperação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe a API do Mercado Bitcoin, é extremamente simples e leve funciona com JSON. Ela é publica não precisa de autentição para os preços

```
https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/BTC/ticker/
```

Retorna

```
{"ticker": 
    {"high": "17770.00000000", 
     "low": "17420.00000000", 
     "vol": "316.44974311", 
     "last": "17430.90199000", 
     "buy": "17430.90199000", 
     "sell": "17487.00000000", 
     "date": 1508016142
    }
}
```

Já para fazer uma função fica bem simples com python

```
    import json
    import urllib2

    def get_btc():
        response = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/BTC/ticker/')
        json_str = response.read()
        btc_data = json.loads(json_str)
        return btc_data['ticker']

btc_ticker = def get_btc()

 print "O preco do Bitcoin agora e: R$ {:.2f}".format(float(btc_ticker['last']))
```

Comment: Amigo, obrigado pela recomendação testei aqui e funcionou direitinho, no entanto como sou novo em Python poderia apenas me explicar o que faz a  parte "['ticker']" após o "return btc_data"...

Comment: O JSON é convertido em um dicionario do python. Nesse dicionario tem a chave "ticker" e dentro dela tem outro dicionario que la tem as informaçoes de preço. Então eu mandei retornar apenas o dicionario que tem os preços.

Comment: Obrigado amigo! Estava sem norte até o momento em que você me esclareceu tudo!